# Ordenar objetos em Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, classificação, order

Boa noite, estou com uma dificultade para ordenar array em javascript, o problema é que preciso ordenar ele primeiramente por quantidade de caracteres, ( *Palavras com mais caracteres aparece por primeiro*), isso já consegui, mas depois disso preciso ordenar as palavras que tem o mesmo numero de caracteres em ordem alfabetica mas não consigo fazer isso sem desrespeitar o primeiro criterio.

segue Meu codigo :

```js
var items = [
    { name: 'one', value: 3 },
    { name: 'three', value: 5 },
    { name: 'mond', value: 4 },
    { name: 'four', value: 4 },
    { name: 'ajdh', value: 4 },
    { name: 'at', value: 2 },
    { name: 'midnight', value: 8 }
  ];
  items.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.value > b.value) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (a.value < b.value) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });

  items.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.value == b.value) {
        if (a.name > b.name) {
            return -1;
          }
          if (a.name < b.name) {
            return 1;
          }
        }
    return 0;
  });
  console.log(items)
```

eu preciso que ele saia assim:

```
[ { name: 'midnight', value: 8 },
  { name: 'three', value: 5 },
  { name: 'ajdh', value: 4 },
  { name: 'four', value: 4 },
  { name: 'mond', value: 4 },
  { name: 'one', value: 3 },
  { name: 'at', value: 2 } ]
```

Repare que, quando a propriedade *value*(Representa a quantidade de caracteres) se repete com o mesmo valor o array precisa ficar em ordem alfabética, mas eu não sei como fazer isso sem bagunçar a ordem restante. Obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não precisa utilizar duas chamadas ao método `sort`, apenas compare o comprimento das palavras com um `if`, se elas tiverem o mesmo comprimento, faça o retorno da função de acordo com a ordem da palavra, caso contrário faça o retorno de acordo com o comprimento da string.

Exemplo (utilizando operador ternário):

```js
var items = [
  { name: 'one', value: 3 },
  { name: 'three', value: 5 },
  { name: 'mond', value: 4 },
  { name: 'four', value: 4 },
  { name: 'ajdh', value: 4 },
  { name: 'at', value: 2 },
  { name: 'midnight', value: 8 }
];

items.sort((a, b) =>
  // se a quantidade de caracteres for igual...
  a.value === b.value ?
  // ordena por ordem alfabética crescente
  a.name.localeCompare(b.name, 'pt-BR') :
  // senão ordena pelo comprimento da palavra decrescente
  b.value - a.value
);

console.log(items);
```

Mas sua lógica de retornar 0 para preservar a ordem das palavras organizadas por tamanho também funciona, você só tem que trocar a ordem em que as palavras estão sendo organizadas por ordem alfabética; retorne `1` quando `a > b`, e `-1` quando `a < b` (ou utilize `localeCompare` como no exemplo acima):

```js
var items = [
  { name: 'one', value: 3 },
  { name: 'three', value: 5 },
  { name: 'mond', value: 4 },
  { name: 'four', value: 4 },
  { name: 'ajdh', value: 4 },
  { name: 'at', value: 2 },
  { name: 'midnight', value: 8 }
];

items.sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value);

items.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.value === b.value) {
    if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
    if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
  }
  return 0;
});

console.log(items);
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!